# for loop to create button jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, button

im having trouble creating buttons dynamically by iterating through a loop. i am fairly new at this so im not sure where im going wrong. here's what i have so far. any advice?

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="giphy.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="buttonDiv"></div> 
  <div id="gifsAppearHere"></div> 
   </body>
   </html>


 var topics = ['bikram', 'yoga', 'vegan', 'vegetarian','nutrition', 'exercise', 'pilates','calisthenics', 'ashtanga', 'vinyasa', 'utkatasana']
 for (var i = 0; i < topics.length; i++) { 
     var buttons = $('<button>'+ topics.text + '</button>') 
     buttons.append('topics'); 
}
```

Comment: Could you also post your html?

Comment: you just created button.... now you need to append the element to any dom element...

Comment: It would be extremely helpful if you posted your html too.

Comment: Please specify clearly what you are trying to do and what "going wrong" means exactly.

Comment: html is posted. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Look again at the documentation. You've used [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append), but you wanted [`appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo) (easy mistake to make).

`append` appends the thing you pass as an argument to the thing you call it on.

`appendTo` appends the thing you call it on to the thing you pass as an argument.

Also note that the selector `"topics"` looks for an element with the *tag name* `topics`, e.g. `<topics>...</topics>`. You may have meant to use a class selector (`".topics"`), or an ID selector (`"#topics"`).

You've also used `topics.text` where I think you meant `topics[i]` (perhaps an error when simplifying the code for the question).

Example:

```js
var topics = ['bikram', 'yoga', 'vegan', 'vegetarian', 'nutrition',    'exercise', 'pilates','calisthenics', 'ashtanga', 'vinyasa', 'utkatasana']
for (var i = 0; i < topics.length; i++) { 
    var buttons = $('<button>'+ topics[i] + '</button>') 
    buttons.appendTo('#topics'); 
}
```

```html
<div id="topics"></div><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: HI! I tried to create space between each of the `button`s by including `&nbsp` but it's not happening. How may I create a space between the buttons? **What I tried:** `var buttons = $('<button>'+ topics[i] + '</button>' + '&nbsp')`.

Answer (score 0):

using inline code

```js
var pages = ['bikram', 'yoga', 'vegan', 'vegetarian', 'nutrition',    'exercise', 'pilates','calisthenics', 'ashtanga', 'vinyasa', 'utkatasana'];
var pageButtons = $('#pageButtons');
for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
  pageButtons.append('<input type="button" id="button' + i + '" value="' + pages[i] + '"/>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pageButtons">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure of what you are trying to do but I this is how I would write that code. This will append 11 buttons with names on them to the body.

I hope this helps!

```
var topics = ['bikram', 'yoga', 'vegan', 'vegetarian', 'nutrition','exercise', 'pilates','calisthenics', 'ashtanga', 'vinyasa', 'utkatasana'];
for (var i = 0; i < topics.length; i++) { 
    var button = $('<button>'+ topics[i] + '</button>') 
    $('.div-with-btns').append(button); /*div that holds your btns*/ 
}
```